# Trouble parsing through file C++

Tags: c++, parsing, getline

So I am getting pretty frustrated and my brain is getting jumbled with my code. I am trying to parse through a miles.dat file that has lines in the format of:

```
Youngstown, OH[4110,8065]115436
Yankton, SD[4288,9739]12011
966
Yakima, WA[4660,12051]49826
1513 2410
Worcester, MA[4227,7180]161799
2964 1520 604
Wisconsin Dells, WI[4363,8977]2521
1149 1817 481 595
Winston-Salem, NC[3610,8025]131885
927 729 2742 1289 494
```

I am trying to pull the name of the city, and then on the next line, there are the costs to all the previous cities from the city right above. My code is so close, but it keeps putting each individual digit instead of just the whole set of them. I want the code to output "1513" and "2410" so I can then put those numbers into my adjacency matrix.

Currently, the output is:

```
Stored: Youngstown, OH
City Count: 1
Press any key to continue . . .
Stored: Yankton, SD
City Count: 2
Press any key to continue . . .
Line: 966
Inputted the cost: 966
Stored: Yakima, WA
City Count: 3
Press any key to continue . . .
Line: 1513 2410
Inputted the cost: 1
Inputted the cost: 15
Inputted the cost: 151
Inputted the cost: 1513
Inputted the cost: 2
Inputted the cost: 24
Inputted the cost: 241
Inputted the cost: 2410
Stored: Worcester, MA
City Count: 4
Press any key to continue . . .
Line: 2964 1520 604
Inputted the cost: 2
Inputted the cost: 29
Inputted the cost: 296
Inputted the cost: 2964
Inputted the cost: 1
Inputted the cost: 15
Inputted the cost: 152
Inputted the cost: 1520
Inputted the cost: 6
Inputted the cost: 60
Inputted the cost: 604
Stored: Wisconsin Dells, WI
City Count: 5
```

My code is:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Turn bracket into int value of "91" (it's ascii code)
    string brack = "[";
    char b = brack[0];
    int bracket = int(b);
    //Variable Declarations
    int city_cost[127][127];
    string cities[127];
    string cost = "";
    int cost_bit = 0;
    int nl_bit = 0;
    int line_count = 1, city_count = 0;
    string line;

    ifstream myfile("miles.dat");
    if (myfile) 
    {
        while (getline(myfile, line))  
        {
            //if the first letter is a alphanumeric letter then dont enter the cost entry section
            if (isalpha(line[0])) {
                cost_bit = 0;
            }
            //Store costs to every other city
            if (cost_bit == 1) {
                cout << "Line: " << line << endl;

                //Seperate numbers in each line char by char, combine, then put that cost in the appropriate city
                for (unsigned int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
                    //find "space" (32 in ascii table) and put the cost in the array, reseting that cost variable each time one is put in
                    char ch = line[i];
                    int ascii = int(ch);//convert char to int
                    if (city_count == 2) {
                        cost = line;
                        cout << "Inputted the cost: " << cost << endl;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (ascii == 32 || ascii == 10 || ascii == 13) {
                        cost = "";
                        continue;
                    }
                    cost = cost + char(ascii);
                    //iterate through each of the previous cities covered and put the cost into them
                    for (int city_count_dec = city_count; city_count_dec != -2; city_count_dec--) {
                        cout << "Inputted the cost: " << cost << endl;
                        city_cost[city_count][city_count_dec] = 0;//replace with cost!!!!!!!! first need to convert to integer (maybe) or just make the city_cost list a string list
                        break;
                    }
                }
                cost_bit = 0;
                cost = "";
            }
            //END store costs to every city

            string new_line = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
                char c = line[i];
                int ai = int(c);//convert char to int

                //skip useless data
                //store city name in array
                if (ai == bracket) {
                    cities[city_count] = new_line;
                    cout << "Stored: " << cities[city_count] << endl;
                    city_count++;
                    cout << "City Count: " << city_count << endl;
                    system("pause");
                    //set cost bit so we know that the next line will be the cost of the cities before it
                    cost_bit = 1;
                    continue;
                }
                else if(cost_bit == 0) {
                    new_line = new_line + c;
                }
            }
            line_count++;
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else cout << "Something went wrong!\n";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: not sure what the question is, but the answer is: use a debugger :P

Comment: Just going to leave some links here: [Parsing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) , [Recursive descent parser](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) , [Backus Naur form](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus–Naur_form) , [Formal Grammar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar)

Answer (score 1):

"*Code never lies. Comments sometime do*"

That `for` loop will only ever iterate once since you break instantly. It is also place at the wrong position in the code.

```
                    //iterate through each of the previous cities covered and put the cost into them
                    for (int city_count_dec = city_count; city_count_dec != -2; city_count_dec--) {
                        cout << "Inputted the cost: " << cost << endl;
                        city_cost[city_count][city_count_dec] = 0;//replace with cost!!!!!!!! first need to convert to integer (maybe) or just make the city_cost list a string list
                        break;
                    }
```

Your code always print the current step, even when you are not at the end of the number. Here is the place in your code you want to process the number found.

```
                if (ascii == 32 || ascii == 10 || ascii == 13) {
                    // This means that you finished parsing a number.
                    // Here, you should print the cost at the screen.
                    cost = "";
                    continue;
                }
```

Comment: Thank you for real feedback! So when I put that for loop in there, then it does not print the cost of the last number in the set. I put the `ascii == 10 || ascii == 13` there to enter the IF statement when its at the end of the line (since there is no space after the last number), but it seems the end of line character is not in the line set, thus not triggering the IF statement. Why is that? I've read that `getline()` puts the `\n` in the line?

Comment: The new line character can change. Use `ascii == int('\n')` in your condition.

Comment: No effect, still skipping that last number :/

Comment: I'll reiterate what someone else said then. Use a debugger and try to find where the unusual behavior happens.

Comment: thanks for the assistance mate